# Why cron jobs' output keeps getting written to ~/dead.letter?

Tags: cron, mail-command, ssmtp

I have a job scheduled by `cron` running every day, and the job is about compressing a folder using `tar`; and I found that the standard output of `tar` keeps getting written into `~/dead.letter` everyday.  The content that gets written is just the list of the files that got compressed, just like what you'll see on the command line when running `tar` manually.

Searching `dead.letter` shows that it's something related to a partial letter that got interrupted before being sent successfully.  I do have a shell script running as daemon that monitors something on the machine and sending out email on specific conditions.  The daemon is started using the following command:

```
setsid ~/send_mail_on_certain_event.sh >~/sendmail.log 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

This is the only place that I use `mail` (actually using `ssmtp`) on the machine, and it's working as I expected (I got the email I wanted).  I don't know if it has anything to do with the `cron` job's output getting written to `dead.letter`.

Comment: If you log in as the user running that cron job, does mail (to that user) work?

Answer (score 1):

When a cron job fails, or has output, cron will try to mail it to the user of the mailjob. When the mail is configured for him.
You have a tar command writing information to stdout and nobody is redirecting stdout. You shoud redirect all stdout and stderr of all your crontab jobs to /dev/null (or some logfile when you are interested in the output).
Example

```
10 0 * * * tar tvf /tmp/tar.tst /home/era >/dev/null 2>&1
```

A bit silly: asking tar to be verbose with the -v flag and throwing away everything tar writes. But that is for when you want to test something like

```
10 10 * * * tar tvf /tmp/tar.tst /home/era
```

Or you can test

```
* * * * * echo "Hello and Goodbye Era"
```

and look for mail under your user account